# (Q) How to use button action in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am currently creating a FaceID-aware app using Swift UI.
What I am trying to do is try FaceID authentication when the user presses the button. When I call class in button action, I get the error message "Result of 'DashboardView' initializer is unused". The related sources are as below. Any help would be appreciated!

```swift
        struct FaceLoginView: View {

        @State private var isUnlocked = false

        var body: some View {
            VStack {

                Button(action: {
                   print("face id tapped!")

                        if self.isUnlocked {
                                 // print("unlocked")
                            DashboardView()
                        } else {
                                // Text("Locked")
                            LoginView()
                        }
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "faceid")
                            .font(.title)
                        Text("faceid")
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .font(.title)
                    }
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("DarkGreen"), Color("LightGreen")]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                    .cornerRadius(40)
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: authenticate)
        }

        func authenticate() {
            let context = LAContext()
            var error: NSError?

            if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
                let reason = "Log in to your account by unlocking FaceID."
                context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) { success, authenticationError in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if success {
                            // authenticated successfully
                            self.isUnlocked = true
                        } else {
                            // there was a problem
                            self.isUnlocked = false
                            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to authenticate")
                        }

                    }
                }
            } else {
                // no biometrics
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Can't evaluate policy")

            }
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out:

i had to comment out some things and change some things because your example wasn't compilable at all but things should be clear to you if you see it ;)

```
struct DashboardView : View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("Dashboardview")
    }
}

struct LoginView : View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("LoginView")
    }
}

struct FaceLoginView: View {

    private var isUnlocked : Bool {
        get {
            return Bool.random()

        }
        set {
            self.isUnlocked = newValue
        }
    }

    @State var navigateToDashboard = false
    @State var navigateToLogin = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {

                NavigationLink(destination: DashboardView(), isActive: $navigateToDashboard) {  EmptyView().hidden()
                }.hidden().frame(height:0)
                NavigationLink(destination: LoginView(), isActive: $navigateToLogin) {  EmptyView().hidden()
                }.hidden().frame(height:0)

                Button(action: {
                    print("face id tapped!")

                    if self.isUnlocked {
                        // print("unlocked")
                        self.navigateToDashboard.toggle()
                    } else {
                        // Text("Locked")
                        self.navigateToLogin.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "faceid")
                            .font(.title)
                        Text("faceid")
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .font(.title)
                    }
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding()
                        //       .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("DarkGreen"), Color("LightGreen")]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                        .cornerRadius(40)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: authenticate)
    }

    func authenticate() {
        //  let context = LAContext()
        var error: NSError?

        //        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        //            let reason = "Log in to your account by unlocking FaceID."
        //            context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) { success, authenticationError in
        //                DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //                    if success {
        //                        // authenticated successfully
        //                        self.isUnlocked = true
        //                    } else {
        //                        // there was a problem
        //                        self.isUnlocked = false
        //                        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to authenticate")
        //                    }
        //
        //                }
        //            }
        //        } else {
        //            // no biometrics
        //            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Can't evaluate policy")
        //
        //        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        FaceLoginView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Chris, Thanks for helping me this problem!. So I got a hint from your code